# How can I implement Samsung Zirconia license check with Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, licensing, copy-protection

I have followed Samsung Zirconia instructions on implementing the license checker for my app.  However, when running the app, it crashed and I receive the following log message.

10-09 21:13:56.754 1107-1127/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.apps.ips.TeacherAidePro2-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libnativeinterface.so"

The problem seems to be that besides a Zirconia.jar file that needs to be in the /libs folder, there are three additional files called libnativeinterface.so that need to be in individual subfolders within the libs directory.  Apparently this works fine in Eclipse, but it is not working for Android Studio.

I find it hard to believe that users working with Android Studio cannot use Zirconia to protect their paid apps.  If anyone has any advice, please help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I managed to answer my own questions, that's to piecing together other topics on this site.

Basically I needed to create a folder called jniLibs in the /source/main folder of the app structure, and copy the .so files in their respective folders.

With that done, Zirconia license protection works fine with Android Studio.  Hope this helps out others that run into this issue.

Comment: I needed this plus a few other things to get Zirconia working in Android Studio 2.2:

install ndk

add "$USE_DEPRECATED_NDK=true" to gradle.properties